# Adding and storing a highscore

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'd like to add a highscore to my android game. I'd like to add it and store for when they return. how do I go about this?
Here's the code for the frame I want it on!

```
lblScore.text = String(score);
gameOver.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, End);
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 


function End(event:TouchEvent): void {
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}

stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, End);

function refreshScores():void {
    lblScore.text = String(score);
    score++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedObject`:

```
var localstorage:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("anyname");

//Save the data to the SharedObject
localstorage.data.score = 100;
//Commit the save
localstorage.flush();

//Get data in the SharedObject, but check to see if it exists
if (localstorage.data.score != undefined){
    //if SharedObject exists so display the data
    trace(localstorage.data.score);
}else{
    //SharedObject does not exists.
}

//If you want to clear the ShareObject
localstorage.clear();
```

If you want to save in a database manner then use `SQLite`